# Semantic role of temporal object

Tags: semantics

Consider the below sentences, all of which have the form Subject-Verb-Object:

> Every day, he spends an hour exercising.
>
> She spent her early life in France.

What is the semantic role that the objects here have? To me, the semantic role appears to be temporal. At first I thought that the semantic role was that of patient, but after some consideration, I ruled this possibility out: for an object to have this semantic role requires that it undergo some sort of action or change, and in both of these sentences the objects do not undergo an action. For instance, in the sentence

> He threw the ball.

'the ball' has the semantic role of patient because it undergoes the action of throwing, so that its position changes (theme). This logic does not apply to the two sentences above: after all, how can 'an hour' undergo the action of spending, or be changed by it? I am therefore unsure of what the semantic role could be.

Some enlightenment would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you feel "this logic does not apply" in "an hour undergoes the action of spending"? Do you feel the same if it were money that was spent?

Comment: I suppose there will be treatments that start with analysing 'an hour' or 'her early life' here as metaphorical units of currency (after 'spend'). [SIL_glossary of linguistic terms](https://glossary.sil.org/term/measure-semantic-role)  classes any measures independently:  '**Measure As A Semantic Role** Definition: 
Measure is a semantic role which notes the quantification of an event.

Examples: 
(English)

_The new coat costs **$70**_'

Comment: This is a straightforward example of the [Time is Money](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf) metaphor theme. _Spend_ only has meaning in the [Commercial Transaction](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf) frame, so any temporal expression with it invokes the metaphor.

Comment: @oerkelens. I cannot understand how 'an hour' can undergo the action of spending in the same way a ball can undergo the action of throwing. Typically, arguments with the semantic role of patient are in some way changed (e.g. if you throw a ball, you change its position); here, an hour isn't changed. In the case of money, I can understand why someone might label 'money' as having the SR of patient, since its 'position' is being changed (e.g., 'He spent some money on some clothes' entails the transfer of money from his bank account to the bank account of the organisation providing the clothes).

Comment: These chunks of time change from being in the future, and as of yet undetermined, to being in the past, and having been fully determined. I am unfamiliar with the semantic role of patient, but naively I do see a change.

Comment: What does it mean to undergo an action: "He ignored the girl" "He memorised the recipe" "He forgot his first day at school" "He explained forgiveness" "He imagined a unicorn" "He denied the existence of God" "He fell in love with Shakespeare's Juliet"...

Comment: @StuartF. You make a very valid point there. In the first three sentences, the objects all appear to have the semantic role of patient, and yet, as you say, it is difficult to discern the actions they undergo. As for the fourth and fifth sentences, I don't think the objects have the semantic role of patient, but rather that of factitive. The concept of forgiveness comes into being by virtue of his explaining it; the image of a unicorn comes into his mind by virtue of his imagining it. In the sixth sentence, I suppose the semantic role of the object is almost the inverse of the...(1/2)

Comment: aforementioned factitive theme, in that the existence of God in his mind is prevented from coming into being by virtue of his denying it. Finally, as for the last sentence, the subject seems to be a metaphorical extension of the SR of patient: here, he undergoes the action of falling in love with Juliet.